# Gruntjs: How to move files from one folder to another

Tags: build, gruntjs

I'm using grunt as build tool. So how do you move files from one folder to another? Currently I use copy and clean. Is there any convenient way?

Comment: You can try `grunt-rename` but it hasn't been updated in 2 years.  The `grunt-contrib-*` plugins are maintained by the Grunt team themselves, I'd encourage you to think outside the box and utilize those plugins for your needs over an outdated 3rd party plugin.

Comment: @theaccordance yes, i use copy and clean to implement 'rename', they're the contrib ones.